# How to prevent two elements from wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I have the following for Google Chrome:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="80px">
            Text
        <td width="100%">
            <form>
                <input style="width:100%" type="text"/>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td width="80px">
            Text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is when you resize the screen to something small, the Submit button wraps around under the textbox. How do I keep the "button" from wrapping (as in the button shows up below the textbox by a few pixels), while keeping the text box as wide as possible?

Comment: Doesn't happen in Safari 6.1, or FF or Chrome latest. What browser?

Comment: Can you post your browser?

Comment: You've got two `</td>` tags on consecutive lines; that's an error.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and the button *always* wraps around, no matter how large the viewport is.

Comment: Oh. You said under the text*box*, not text.

Comment: can the table be wrapped within a form?

Comment: You have missed the closing </td> for the first <td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add the following styles to the `form` to prevent it from wrapping:

```
form{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then remove the style `width=100%` from the input, which causes it to occupy all of the horizontal space within the `td`.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/B4eWz/

Comment: If the width of the textbox is 100% how do you expect the button not to wrap?

Comment: I want the textbox to occupy as much of the screen as possible. It looks like on the right side, the "Text" overlaps the button from fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/N36a7/

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="80px">Text</td>
            <td width="100%">
                <input style="width:100%" type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </td>
            <td width="80px">Text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Just give the button it's own td.